# Empty the search bar of a datatable by default instead of including the highlighted text

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to make the Search bar of the datatable empty instead of having the `'setosa'` inside it by default while keeping the `'setosa'` highlighted inside the table? Or at least find another way to highlight or underline the `'setosa'`?

```
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(

    ),
    dashboardBody(
        DT::dataTableOutput("t")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$t <- renderDT(

        datatable(iris, options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = 'setosa'))) 
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: So if the end-user searches something else it will invoke the highlight again or do you want `da` being highlighted only on start?

Comment: The 'da' should be always highlighted or underlined inside the table. The search bar should work normaly like for example in datatable(mtcars). It should be empty until the user will try to search for something and type in it.

Comment: Do u need only rownames to be highlighted?

Comment: I edited to make more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you can do something like this.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        DT::dataTableOutput("t")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
        mydata <- iris
        rownames(mydata) <- gsub("setosa",tags$span(style="color:red", "setosa"),rownames(mydata))
        for(i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
            mydata[,i] <- gsub("setosa",tags$span(style="color:red", "setosa"),mydata[,i])
        }
        mydata
    })

    output$t <- renderDT(
        datatable(data(), options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = '')), escape = F)  
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I do not want to use an extra textbox. I need the word setosa to be highlighted or underlined always somehow and the search bar to be empty until the user uses it.

Comment: here you go, `setosa` is always highlighted now